# Does Heroku Scheduler add-on have a config file?

Tags: ruby, heroku, scheduler

I was wondering if Heroku Scheduler add-on for Ruby allows some kind of config file where I can set there what tasks to run and when, the same way that I would do it from the Heroku dashboard.

The reason I want this is because I have a lot of apps (development, staging, production) and I am too lazy to go set the Scheduler configuration for each one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The Heroku Scheduler add-on can only be configured through the web app.